# Get month year pattern just with numbers by current culture

Tags: c#, localization, datetime-format

Is there a way to get a localised pattern for month and year, where the month is just a number?

I found `DateTimeFormatInfo.YearMonthPattern` but this returns the full month name. I am looking for an pattern like `MM.YYYY` (09.2021) or `YYYY/MM` (2021/09) depending on the current culture.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to `convert` the date to your expected form. like
`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM")`

Comment: Yes, but I need the patter (for example "yyyy/MM") dynamic based on the culture info. For Example, in Germany it should be "MM.yyyy".